# How To Add Function With A Navigator Into On press In React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
              onPressAddCart={this.addToCart}
              onPressViewCart={() => navigation.navigate(homeTabs.cart)}
```

> How do I add both Navigator and the function into one on press button

```
onPressAddCart={this.addToCart && () => navigation.navigate(homeTabs.cart)}
```

Comment: Why don't you create a function that includes the two actions ?

Comment: can you explain your question more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to do multiple things with one button press. Buttons have an onPress prop that can take in a function that will run when it is pressed (https://reactnative.dev/docs/button).

You could make a separate function that combines both of those things, as Dani mentioned in the comments. You can also add in whatever things you need to happen. Here is an example implementation:

```
const onPress = () => {
  this.addToCart()
  navigation.navigate(homeTabs.cart)
  someOtherFunction()
  ...
}

<Button onPress={onPress}/>
```

Now when the button is pressed, in will call the onPress function you defined, and do everything inside of that.